# paypal ipn coming up invalid but checking the ipn response its verified

Tags: django, python-3.x, paypal

What I am getting:

Paypal response 200 - suggesting that I am receiving the IPN information. This is also showing on my Django admin sign as I can see the IPN received and the IPN details.

The IPN I am receiving on my Django admin side shows a RESPONSE = VERIFIED.

Nonetheless, the response I am getting to my URL Receiver is coming back INVALID. (This is the r.text response that I am getting in the below code).

Things I checked:

As far as I can tell, I am posting and  receiving from the Paypal Sandbox.

I updated the Paypal settings to be UTF-8.

I am using my paypal sandbox buyer email to buy and facilitator email to get the purchase.

The code is pretty straight forwards below. Please let me know if more information is needed to assess where my issue is occurring.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

import requests
import sqlite3
import time
import sys
import urllib.parse


from paypal.standard.forms import PayPalPaymentsForm
from paypal.standard.models import ST_PP_COMPLETED
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import valid_ipn_received, invalid_ipn_received

from payment.models import Profile


def payment_view(request):

    host = request.get_host()

    # What you want the button to do.
    paypal_dict = {
        "business": "facilitator@gmail.com",
        "cmd": '_xclick-subscriptions',
        "item_name": "Monthly Subscription",
        "amount": "6.99",
        "a3": "6.99",
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "p3": "1",
        "t3": "M",
        "src": "1",
        "sra": "1",
        "no_note": "1",
        "modify": "1",
        "notify_url": "http://{}{}".format(host, reverse('paypal-ipn')),
        "return_url": "http://{}{}".format(host, reverse('payment:done')),
        "cancel_return": "http://{}{}".format(host, 
reverse('payment:canceled')),
     "custom": request.user.username
            }

# Create the instance.
form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict, button_type="subscribe")
context = {"form": form}
return render(request, "payment.html", context)



VERIFY_URL_PROD = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'
VERIFY_URL_TEST = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'

VERIFY_URL = VERIFY_URL_TEST

param_str = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
params = urllib.parse.parse_qsl(param_str)
params.append(('cmd', '_notify-validate'))
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'host': 'www.paypal.com'}
r = requests.post(VERIFY_URL, params=params, headers=headers, verify=True)
r.raise_for_status()

if r.text == 'VERIFIED':
    with open('/tmp/ipnout.txt','a') as f:
            f.write('valid')

elif r.text == 'INVALID':
    with open('/tmp/ipnout.txt','a') as f:
            f.write(r.text)

else:
    with open('/tmp/ipnout.txt','a') as f:
            f.write('neither')
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294703/paypal-convertings-spaces-in-cart-form-to-plus-sign) may be the same as the problem you're having.

Comment: Using the solution from that thread did not lead to a change. I added the enctype="multipart/form-data" to the button.

Answer (score 0):

This issue will happen when you tried to use different transaction ID (buyers transaction ID).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using anything to expose you dev machine to the web? eg ngrok?
Use the url generated by ngrok as the ipn and return url in paypals' settings (https).
you'll also need to set the Site name settings to the exposed url

Check the ipn history in paypal for error messages

although getting old, i built an implementation using a few snippets from here: http://greenash.net.au/thoughts/2014/03/using-paypal-wps-with-cartridge-mezzanine-django/